# Não consigo trocar tamanho da fonte em C# (Property or indexer 'Font.Size' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only)

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu fiz uma Trackbar pra trocar o tamanho da fonte no VisualStudio Express 2015,mas quando eu tento mudar a fonte ele retorna o erro "Property or indexer 'Font.Size' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" e eu não tenho ideia do que fazer.
Código:

```
    private void FontTrackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblFontSize.Text = FontTrackBar.Value.ToString();       //seta o valor da barra numa label
        int FontSizeInt = FontTrackBar.Value;                   //Variavel com o valor da trackbar
        Form1.DefaultFont.Size = FontTrackBar.Value; //Aqui eu tento setar o tamanho da fonte e dá erro
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FontTrackBar.Value = Convert.ToInt16(8);                //seta o padrão da fonte   
        lblFontSize.Text = FontTrackBar.Value.ToString();
    }
```

Edit: Corrigi um erro agora mas continua do mesmo jeito.
[image: Print do Codigo com o erro]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa propriedade é somente leitura como dito no própria erro: `Property or indexer 'Font.Size' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only` se quiser mudar o tamanho da fonte do formulário tem que ser pela caixa de propriedades ou então pela instância da sua classe, exemplo:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Font = new Font("Arial", 12);
```

ou se estiver na instância:

```
this.Font = new Font("Arial", 12);
```

no seu código:

```
private void FontTrackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblFontSize.Text = FontTrackBar.Value.ToString();
    int FontSizeInt = FontTrackBar.Value;
    this.Font = new Font(DefaultFont.FontFamily.Name, FontTrackBar.Value); // aqui
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisa construir outro objeto [`Font`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). Além disso, você não pode alterar a propriedade `DefaultFont` de algum controle, esta é uma propriedade estática usada para *fallback*.

Neste caso, é necessário alterar o valor da propriedade de instância [`Font`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.font?view=netcore-3.1).

```
Font = new Font(DefaultFont.FontFamily, novoTamanho);
```

---

Exemplo funcionando:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        Text = "Título";

        var button = new Button
        {
            Size = new Size(50, 30),
            Location = new Point(10, 10),
            Text = "Texto"
        };

        button.Click += ChangeFont;

        Controls.Add(button);

    }

    public void ChangeFont(object _, EventArgs __) 
        => Font = new Font(DefaultFont.FontFamily, Font.Size + 1);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]